# How to convert categorial data to indices and print assignment?

Tags: python, pandas, categorical-data

**Context**
I have a series with categorial data. My goal is to convert it to indices like in the example above. However, there are two other requirements:

- nan values should stay nan and not converted to an index e.g. -1
- I would like to print the assignment of category to index

---

**Code**

```py
red    -> 0
blue   -> 1
green  -> 2
nan    -> nan
red    -> 0
yellow -> 3
green  -> 2
nan    -> nan

series = series.astype('category').cat.codes
```

**Question**

How can I achieve this goal?

Comment: Why don't you replace -1 with np.nan after this code

Comment: the -1 used in categorical data is there for efficiency, either use a categorical and don't mess with the internals, or use a custom order and map your own values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The -1 used in categorical data is there for efficiency, either use a categorical and don't mess with the internals, or use a custom order and map your own values.

##### categorical

You can use ordered categories as the codes will be used in order (first one is 0, second is 1, etc.), **but NaN will be -1**:

```
df['col'] = pd.Categorical(df['col'], ordered=True,
                           categories=['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow'])
```

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['blue', 'red', 'yellow', np.nan]})

df['col'] = pd.Categorical(df['col'], ordered=True,
                           categories=['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow'])

print(df['col'].cat.codes)
```

Output:

```
0    1
1    0
2    3
3   -1
dtype: int8
```

##### custom values

If you really need NaN as NaN, then a `Categorical` is not appropriate, instead use a [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df['col'] = df['col'].map({'red': 0, 'blue': 1, 'green': 2, 'yellow': 3})
print(df)
```

Or, automatically:

```
order = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow']

df['col'] = df['col'].map({k: v for v, k in enumerate(order)})

print(df)
```

Output:

```
   col
0  1.0
1  0.0
2  3.0
3  NaN
```

Comment: I can not catch up your speed mozway . You're idol to me ) @mozway

Answer (score 0):

If you're using it for machine-learning, try
https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/about_dataset_features

```
pip install datasets
```

Usage:

```
import numpy as np
from datasets import ClassLabel


data = pd.Series(['red', 'blue', 'green', np.NaN, 'red', 'yellow', 'green', np.NaN])

# Convert NaN to string.
data = data.fillna('nan')

# Get unique classes.
unique_labels = list(set(data))

# Create the ClassLabel object.
mapper = ClassLabel(len(unique_labels), unique_labels)

# Apply the str2int mappings.
data.apply(mapper.str2int)
```

[out]:

```
0    3
1    2
2    1
3    0
4    3
5    4
6    1
7    0
dtype: int64
```

---

```
>>> mapper = ClassLabel(5, ['nan', 'green', 'blue', 'red', 'yellow'])
>>> mapper
ClassLabel(names=['nan', 'green', 'blue', 'red', 'yellow'], id=None)
```

Comment: If you're using it to train some sort of classifier, here's an example usage: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75717951/610569